# error C2156: pragma must be outside function - why is it happening in this case?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, pragma

Gives this set of 4 files:

file1.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <windows.h>
```

file1.cpp:

```
#include "file1.h"
```

file2.h:

```
#pragma once

#define N 666
```

file2.cpp:

```
#include "file2.h"
#include "file1.h"
```

When i try to compile file2.cpp with visual studio 2015 compiler `cl -c file2.cpp` i'll get a bunch of errors:

```
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.24215.1 for x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

file2.cpp
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\um\winnt.h(1179): error C2059: syntax error: 'constant'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\um\winnt.h(2149): error C2598: linkage specification must be at global scope
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\um\winnt.h(4807): error C2598: linkage specification must be at global scope
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\um\winnt.h(4859): error C2156: pragma must be outside function
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\um\winnt.h(4991): error C2598: linkage specification must be at global scope
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\um\winnt.h(5050): error C2156: pragma must be outside function
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\um\winnt.h(5051): error C2156: pragma must be outside function
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\um\winnt.h(5052): error C2156: pragma must be outside function
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\um\winnt.h(5053): error C2156: pragma must be outside function
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\um\winnt.h(5054): error C2156: pragma must be outside function
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\um\winnt.h(5055): error C2156: pragma must be outside function
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\um\winnt.h(5078): error C2156: pragma must be outside function
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\um\winnt.h(5079): error C2156: pragma must be outside function
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\um\winnt.h(5134): error C2156: pragma must be outside function
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\um\winnt.h(5135): error C2156: pragma must be outside function
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\um\winnt.h(5136): error C2156: pragma must be outside function
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\um\winnt.h(5137): error C2156: pragma must be outside function
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\um\winnt.h(15420): error C2059: syntax error: 'constant'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\um\winnt.h(15420): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\um\winnt.h(15439): error C2059: syntax error: 'constant'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\um\winnt.h(15439): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
```

But if i comment the line `#define N 666` the file will be compiled ok. Could anyone explain me what's going on here? Cos I don't get it, [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ehfz1209.aspx) aren't solving me anything.

Comment: Understand [what the macro actually does](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace) and consider that `N` is a commonly used identifier.

Comment: My best guess would be that your macro definition clobbers something in header `um/winnt.h`, which apparently is included by `windows.h`.  In that case flipping the order of the `#include` directives in file2.cpp should also resolve the problem.

Comment: Why use a macro when a `const int` would do? And why is it global? And why doesn't it have a better, more descriptive, name than "N"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object-like macro `N` collides with `windows.h`, which includes `winnt.h`.

For instance:

```
extern "C++" // templates cannot be declared to have 'C' linkage
template <typename T, size_t N>
char (*RtlpNumberOf( UNALIGNED T (&)[N] ))[N];
```

I would suggest to avoid using macros whenever you can. In both C and C++, you might consider to replace macro definition with const object:

```
const int N = 666;
```

(note that in C you may likely use `static const`, since the default linkage of `const` is external)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that macro would be visible on the `windows.h` file

Answer (score 1):

You should not define macros with such short names like "N". With almost 100% probability this will collide with something inside the headers you include afterwards, like Windows.h: If somewhere inside of it a "N" is mentioned, the preprocessor will replace it by 666, possibly making the program ill-formed or causing other weird pre-processor effects that are hard to debug and a nightmare for any user of your header file, including yourself.

Anyway, if you insist on doing it (which you really shouldn't, especially in header files), make sure you #define N after including any header:

```
#include "file1.h"
#include "file2.h"
```

which will resolve to

```
#include <windows.h>
#define N666
```

By the way the preprocessor works, the order in which you include per translation unit is important.